# Set the position for service CMake files

Tags: cmake, config

I'm building a C[++] project with CMake.
After running `cmake --build ...` I have a `build` folder in my project containing my binary plus some CMake service file like that:

```
.
|____CMakeLists.txt
|____build
| |____compile_commands.json
| |____CMakeFiles
| |____Makefile
| |____cmake_install.cmake
| |____CMakeCache.txt
| |____project.a
| |____.cmake
|____include
|____src
```

Is it possible to configure CMake to move all those files (except the actually built binaries) to some other place?
I can imagine something like:

```
.
|____CMakeLists.txt
|____build
| |____project.a
| |____.cmake
|   |____compile_commands.json
|   |____CMakeFiles
|   |____Makefile
|   |____cmake_install.cmake
|   |____CMakeCache.txt
|   |____etc
|   |____...
|____include
|____src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to force cmake to generate a specific file structure well supported. I recommend approaching the problem from the other end instead: Determine the location where cmake outputs the binaries. You simply need to set some or all of the following variables:

- [`CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- [`CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- [`CMAKE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)
- [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html)

[CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) would be a convenient place to set this kind of info:

```
...
configurePresets": [
{
    ...
    "cacheVariables": {

        "CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY": {
          "type": "PATH",
          "value": "${sourceDir}/build_binaries"
        },
        "CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY": {
          "type": "PATH",
          "value": "${sourceDir}/build_binaries"
        },
        "CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY": {
          "type": "PATH",
          "value": "${sourceDir}/build_binaries"
        },
        "CMAKE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY": {
          "type": "PATH",
          "value": "${sourceDir}/build_binaries"
        }
  },
  ...
},
...
]
...
```

This only provides default values though. The corresponding target properties (e.g. `RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`) take precedence. Furthermore there's the possibility of the cache variables being shadowed by variables of the same name specified in your cmake files.

---

Note: If you want to put the binaries for a project in a file structure suitable for deployment, you should be using [`install()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/install.html) functionality instead.

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your answer. You've understood the problem exactly correctly.
Both of your proposals (with variables and install) will work, but...
I'm a big fan of semantics. As far as I can see there is a CMAKE_BINARY_DIR variable which is what I'd like to use for my binaries. But seems like CMake wants to put it's service files exactly there. As for the "install" solution, I understand it as a stage when built binaries are installed into some destination, wheras I want not to "install" something but rather to prepare it for deployment.
Anyways, thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @IliaLiachin assuming you've only used relative paths with `install()`, you can "install" the build results to a local directory using `cmake --install buildDir --prefix installDir` which could be convenient, if you want to place the files into the same directory structure as needed for the target system. In fact cpack does exactly that: it runs the cmake install logic to install the files into a subdirectory of the build directory and then "collects" the files with the actual package builder...